# How to make symbols with Mapserver?

Tags: mapserver

I want to convert some Mapinfo styles to Mapserver.
[Here](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html#),  I found some examples on how to make symbols. But I don't understand how it works.

For example a dashed line:

```
SYMBOL
 NAME "mapinfo-pen-73"
 TYPE vector
 FILLED true
 POINTS
  5 25
  25 30
  45 30
  35 25
END # Points
ANCHORPOINT 0.5 0
END # SYMBOL
```

And i get my dashed line.

What does the POINTS block mean? I can't find any explanation, how to write POINTS by self. Where i can find documentation?

**UPDATE**

After i'd readed @user30184 and @Andreas answers i'm steal dont understand POINTS block.

I'm looking on my example in map:

[image]

i see dashed line.
If POINTS it is a polygons shape it's look like:

[image]

This moment dont clear for me. Why shape form different with dashed like form?

Im missed with Y axe. But anyway shape form very strange.

Comment: Points means Shape here. The given coordinate pairs (Points) form a shaped area, which represents the symbol. Inside a map layer you can then use this symble and color it, size it or whatever by binding it to an feature/attribute.

Comment: I think that this description is quite good: http://www.mapplus.ch/neapoljs-dojo/v2.5.2/wmcm/help/MapServer/sym_vector.htm The tricky part is that the symbol coordinate system is upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to construct symbols for MapServer is explained in the document that you have been reading. http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/symbology/construction.html.

How to use POINTS is written rather unclearly

> For symbols of TYPE vector and ellipse the shape of the symbol  by
>   setting X and Y values in a local two dimensional coordinate system
>   with X values increasing to the right and Y values increasing
>   downwards. The coordinates defining the symbol is listed in the POINTS
>   parameter, which is explicitly ended using END. Negative values should
>   not be used.

Example should clarify the usage. Let's make an unfilled triangle symbol with corners at coordinates (0 0), (2 0), and (2 1).

[image]

```
SYMBOL
  NAME "triangle"
  TYPE vector
  POINTS
    0 0
    2 0
    2 1
    0 0
  END # POINTS
END # SYMBOL
```